# Restructure JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I now have a JSON response from the server like, but i want to restructure it, according to dates. for e.g i now have

```
{
"items":
    [
        {
            "A": [
                {
                    "name": "a",
                    "date": "2/10/2010",
                    "sales": "100"
                },
                {
                    "name": "b",
                    "date": "6/10/2010",
                    "sales": "400"
                }
            ],
            "B": [
                {
                    "name": "c",
                    "date": "2/10/2010",
                    "sales": "1000"
                },
                {
                    "name": "d",
                    "date": "6/10/2010",
                    "sales": "400"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "C": [
                {
                    "name": "a",
                    "date": "10/10/2010",
                    "sales": "100"
                },
                {
                    "name": "b",
                    "date": "6/10/2010",
                    "sales": "100"
                }
            ],
            "D": [
                {
                    "name": "c",
                    "date": "2/10/2010",
                    "sales": "300"
                },
                {
                    "name": "c",
                    "date": "2/10/2010",
                    "sales": "1100"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

but now i want to restructure by dates, for a particular day need to know all the sales to have like,

```
    {
    "date1" : [sales, sales, sales],
    "date2" : [sales, sales],
    "date3" : [sales]
    }
```

how can this be done?

Comment: Can you confirm your JSON structure? as it is now, it is invalid.

Comment: Your JSON is not valid.  What have you tried to do?

Comment: Are you parsing the JSON manually, or letting jQuery parse it for you? If manually, you could use a [reviver function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/ can help you validate your json

Comment: possible duplicate of [create a new JSON, from a existing JSON response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15279221/create-a-new-json-from-a-existing-json-response) - please do not delete and recreate your questions, but edit them.

Comment: sorry folks. new to Javascript and JSON. i did edit the question, and its a valid JSON now

Comment: If you're doing this sort of manipulation often in your application, you might want to check out jlinq: http://hugoware.net/projects/jlinq

`var results = jlinq.from(JSON).group("date");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can only assume that you want this:

```
var arr = JSON.parse(response); // or something like that (assuming valid JSON)
                                // or just assign the array literal

var result = {};
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    var date = arr[i].date,
        sales = arr[i].sales;
    if (date in result)
        result[date].push(sales);
    else
        result[date] = [sales];
}
```

Comment: @MikeRobinson: `in` is really fine. `hasOwnProperty` used like in your edit has similar problems.

Comment: After I edited that I did some more reading. Right you are. Nice solution too.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you get your JSON worked out:

```
<?php
$list = array(
    array(
        'product'   => 'a',
        'date'      => '2012-08-01',
        'sales'     => 500,
    ),
    array(
        'product'   => 'b',
        'date'      => '2012-08-02',
        'sales'     => 600,
    ),
    array(
        'product'   => 'c',
        'date'      => '2012-08-01',
        'sales'     => 250,
    ),
    array(
        'product'   => 'd',
        'date'      => '2012-08-02',
        'sales'     => 800,
    ),
);

echo json_encode($list);
?>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var JSON = '<?php echo json_encode($list); ?>';
var pJson = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON);

var cArray = new Array();

for each ( i in pJson ) {
         if ( typeof cArray[i.date] == 'undefined' ) {
                cArray[i.date] = Array();
         }
        cArray[i.date].push(i.sales);
}
</script>
```

I added the php section to show what a JSON string should look like.  This solution also requires jQuery.

Comment: There is no reason to output JSON as strings into scripts, you should just output Object literals. And your way is very error-prone, as you forgot to escape the JSON string. Try it with only one JSON value that includes a `"` or `'` and your solution blows up.

Comment: I understand Bergi, the PHP and outputting the JSON was simply so he/she could see a valid JSON string.  I mentioned this is ASSUMING he had his/her JSON string worked out.  Sorry for posting after your answer, I did not refresh the page.