# restructure Json with a function

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON response from the xlsx file like, but I want to restructure it with a function.

this is de old code:

```
{
  "Produtos": [
    [
      "SP",
      "Hamburgueria"
    ],
    [
      null,
      null,
      "IN00001282",
      "Batata 7 MM Corte Fino McCain 2,25 Kg - Caixa com 8 Unidades",
      "$8.85",
      "$1.11"
    ],
    [
      null,
      null,
      "IN000155937",
      "Copo De Fritas 480 ml Kraft - 1000 Unidades",
      "$394.74",
      "$0.39"
    ]
  ]
}
```

And this is a restructured code:

```
{
    "Produtos": {
        "SP": {
            "Hamburgueria": [
                [
                    null,
                    null,
                    "IN00001282",
                    "Batata 7 MM Corte Fino McCain 2,25 Kg - Caixa com 8 Unidades",
                    "$8.85",
                    "$1.11"
                ],
                [
                    null,
                    null,
                    "IN00001282",
                    "Batata 7 MM Corte Fino McCain 2,25 Kg - Caixa com 8 Unidades",
                    "$8.85",
                    "$1.11"
                ]
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Could anyone please help me with Javascript code to restructure the JSON. I am unable to get the structuring right.

Thanks

Comment: `I am unable to get the structuring right.` What have you tried? Note that JSON is a *method of formatting a string*, which is *different* from an Object.

Comment: Do you only have `"SP",
      "Hamburgueria"` in your `Produtos`?

Comment: I tried to convert json to string and manipulate it, but it did not work

Comment: I have also: RJ, BR and Japanese, Pizza and Sweets, for all categories

Comment: Your current structure is very unclear. Give another example. Show us what you tried.  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15279685/restructure-json?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `reduce` to restructure the object.

```js
let oldObj={"Produtos":[["SP","Hamburgueria"],[null,null,"IN00001282","Batata 7 MM Corte Fino McCain 2,25 Kg - Caixa com 8 Unidades","$8.85","$1.11"],[null,null,"IN000155937","Copo De Fritas 480 ml Kraft - 1000 Unidades","$394.74","$0.39"]]}

let newObj = Object.entries(oldObj).reduce((c, v) => {
  let [l, a] = v, h = a.shift();
  c[l] = h.reverse().reduce((r, o) => {return {[o]: r};}, a);
  return c;
}, {})

console.log(newObj);
```

Doc: [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: Happy to helo @VictorBatista